# Using Cypher with LIMIT and SKIP: Does Cypher always return data in the same order?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

Does cypher always return results from the same query in the same order? (Assuming no modifications are made to the DB between queries?)

So for example:

```
Query 1: return n LIMIT 100 // returns from 1 to 100?
Query 2: return n SKIP 100 LIMIT 100 // does this return from 101 onwards?
```

Does query 2 effectively pick-up where query 1 leaves off? I don't want to apply any sorting as I am assuming that this would be counter-productive for performance.

For some background -> I am using py2neo to stream results from a query, but I find that if I return more than 10,000,000 items (with four properties returned per item) then I get an error that py2neo has run out of VM. So what I would like to do is run two separate queries so that I can return all of the information, but preferably without duplicates...hence the above question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/neo4j/vPYg5n9eV40/HivYGsnNh3gJ) says there is no default ordering of how data is saved in graph. If you just do a `LIMIT` it will just pick first n objects from the underlying set whereas using `ORDERBY LIMIT` will first order every thing and then give the first n results. More info on this : [here](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/10/27/neo4j-cypher-profiling-order-by-limit-vs-limit/).

So to answer your question, your queries will work until the moment that the underlying graph dataset is modified. Its quite possible the dataset gets modified and then the LIMIT will return a different set of results.